# How can I make sure the <head> JS runs in a puppeteer session?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I'm trying to resize an SVG based on runtime characteristics handed to a method. I'm doing so with puppeteer, so the SVG renders as it would in a browser window. What I want to be able to do is resize the SVG render area arbitrarily.

Given SVG content as a string, and height and width, basically I have the following:

```js
await page.setViewport({ height, width });
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
await page.setContent(`<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
const setDims = () => {
const newHeight = ${height};
const newWidth = ${width};

const parentSvg=document.getElementById("SVGthing")
parentSvg.setAttribute('height', newHeight.toString(10));
parentSvg.setAttribute('width', newWidth.toString(10));
};
</script>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0; margin:0" onload="setDims()">
${svg}
</body>
</html>`);
await page.waitForNetworkIdle();
```

But the rendered port is right, the SVG loads (including network resources, etc) but the resizing does NOT happen; I can't tell if the onload() is running or not. If I run the generated output in a browser window, the resizing occurs as expected, so I *think* Puppeteer is just not executing the code, or I'm not waiting for the code to run; I just don't know *how* to wait until the code is run, offhand.

Comment: try adding the whole code into an async function as the code is showing errors as await is valid in only async function

Comment: I didn't show the whole method, because it has code that isn't relevant for the question as a whole. But in practice, the method IS in an async method, and it still doesn't execute the "onload" block by the time I grab a screenshot with `await page.screenshot(...)`.

Comment: this works locally. how do you get `svg` variable, try hardcoding it

Comment: The `svg` variable contains a valid SVG, it's actually generated but I can also manually load it from the filesystem. The HTML file equivalent works fine, if I take the template and manually load the SVG inside; load it in a browser like Brave or whatever, and it resizes as expected. It's only puppeteer that has the behavior.

Comment: most likely, there's something wrong with your `svg`,  check this line especially: `const parentSvg=document.getElementById("SVGthing")`, you're most likely setting size on the container, not the `svg`, or maybe there's some style overriding yours.. that's why I suggested hardcoding it and running it with puppeteer, and debug it there. you might include that `svg`, because it's impossible to reproduce

Comment: The SVG actually does have the width and height set on it. Unfortunately, I was able to run the code manually and have it render and resize properly; it was only the invocation via nodejs that failed. I found a workaround where I execute code *outside* of the generated content, and that's working.